# Problem inheriting member functions with similar signatures in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, mfc

I have an MFC C++ program that contains two classes, as follows;

```
struct MyStruct
{
'
'
};

class   Class1
{ 
public:
   virtual MyStruct *MyFunc(LPCTSTR x);
   virtual void MyFunc(MyStruct *x);
'
'
};

class Class2 : public Class1
{
public:
  virtual void MyFunc(MyStruct *x);
'
'
};

main()
{
'
'
  CString Str = _T("WTF");
  Class2 a;
  a.MyFunc(Str);
'
'
}
```

When I compile this  under VS2003 code I get **error C2664: 'MyFunc' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'class CString' to 'struct MyStruct *'** whereas I would have expected the compiler to pick up the globally defined conversion from CString to LPCTSTR and call the base member MyStruct *MyFunc(LPCTSTR x);  Note that if I remove virtual void MyFunc(MyStruct *x); from the definition of Class2 it compiles just fine.

I'm probably missing something pretty simple here, but I can't figure out why this doesn't work.  Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design to handle what is called the "fragile base class" problem.

Let's assume you have classes like this:

```
struct A
{
    void MyFunc(long)  {...}
}

struct B : A
{
    void MyFunc(long) { ... }
}
....
B  b;
b.MyFunc(5);
```

Here's we would call B:MyFunc(long) because ints silently convert to longs.

But say someone later changed struct A to:

```
struct A
{
    void MyFunc(long)  {...}
    void MyFunc(int)   {...}
}
```

Now, if override worked like you assumed, that the call to `b.MyFunc(5)` would change to call to A::MyFunc(int) --- even though neither your calling code nor struct B, the class you are actual using, changed.   This was deemed worse a little confusion.

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense once you know why.

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
using Class1::MyFunc;
```

in Class2.  Classes are nested scopes and name lookup stop when a match is found.  The same problem can occur with nested namespaces (with the same solution), but is less common in practice.

Answer (score -1):

you should add to Class2

```
virtual MyStruct *MyFunc(LPCTSTR x)
{
    return Class1::MyFunc(x);
}
```

or specify explicitly the base class method when you call it:

```
a.Class1::MyFunc(Str);
```

Comment: The solution is good, but the statement incorrect. What is there is called method hiding. If a function name is found in the current scope the compiler doesn't search it anymore, even if the signature doesn't match.